# Method not found: 'Void Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper`1..ctor(Boolean)'

Tags: wpf, autofac, caliburn.micro, wpf-4.0

I was working on a `WPF` project using these packages:

```
<package id="Autofac" version="3.0.2" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Caliburn.Micro" version="1.5.1" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Caliburn.Micro.Autofac" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Until yesterday that I update packages to:

```
<package id="Autofac" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Caliburn.Micro" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Caliburn.Micro.Autofac" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

I mean, I update `Autofac` from `3.0.2` to `3.1.1` and `Caliburn.Micro` from `1.5.1` to `1.5.2` (by using `Nuget Package Manager`). After that, I cannot run the project. I get this error:

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyAppBootstrapper' that
>   matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line
>   number '9' and line position '22'.

at this line in `App.xaml`:

> 

The inner exception message is:

> {"Method not found: 'Void
>   Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper`1..ctor(Boolean)'."}

Is there any point to upgrading I did that I missed?

The complete stack trace:

```
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
at Shivar.Tameshk.Server.UI.App.InitializeComponent() in d:\Projects\Shivar.Tameshk\Tameshk\Server\Shivar.Tameshk.Server.UI\App.xaml:line 1
at Shivar.Tameshk.Server.UI.App.Main() in d:\Projects\Shivar.Tameshk\Tameshk\Server\Shivar.Tameshk.Server.UI\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

and the inner exception's stack:

```
at Caliburn.Micro.Autofac.AutofacBootstrapper`1..ctor()
at Shivar.Tameshk.Server.UI.ServerUiBootstrapper..ctor() in d:\Projects\Shivar.Tameshk\Tameshk\Server\Shivar.Tameshk.Server.UI\ServerUiBootstrapper.cs:line 28
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I found the answer :) The problem is here:

The `Caliburn.Micro.Autofac.AutofacBootstrapper<TRootViewModel>` in *Caliburn.Micro.Autofac* nuget package (*version="1.5.0"*) extends `Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper<TRootModel>` in *Caliburn.Micro* package, and has a constructor like this:

```
public AutofacBootstrapper() : base(true) { }
```

It means it calls the `base.ctor` by passing a `boolean` argument (`base.ctor(bool)`). And here is the thing. The `Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper<TRootModel>` in version `1.5.1` has a constructor with a `bool` parameter:

```
public Bootstrapper(bool useApplication = true) : base(useApplication) {
  this.Start();
}
```

while in version `1.5.2`, it has only one parameter-less constructor:

```
public Bootstrapper() : base(true) {
  this.Start();
}
```

Here is the signatures:

```
// Assembly: Caliburn.Micro.Autofac, Version=1.5.0.0
namespace Caliburn.Micro.Autofac {
    public class AutofacBootstrapper<TRootViewModel> : Bootstrapper<TRootViewModel> {
        public AutofacBootstrapper() : base(true) { }
    }
}

// Assembly: Caliburn.Micro, Version=1.5.1.0
namespace Caliburn.Micro {
    public class Bootstrapper<TRootModel> : BootstrapperBase {
        public Bootstrapper(bool useApplication = true) : base(useApplication) {
            this.Start();
        }
    }
}

// Assembly: Caliburn.Micro, Version=1.5.2.0
namespace Caliburn.Micro {
    public class Bootstrapper<TRootModel> : BootstrapperBase {
        public Bootstrapper() : base(true) {
            this.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

So, the `Caliburn.Micro.Autofac, Version=1.5.0.0` cannot be used with `Caliburn.Micro, Version=1.5.2.0` and you have to create your own `AutofacBootstrapper`, which is easy to implement by referring the original one ([here](http://buksbaum.us/2010/08/20/bootstrapping-caliburn-micro-with-autofac/)) or reading the nuget packages source. Also, [here](https://gist.github.com/kavand/6272568) is my re-implemented one, if you need.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time :) Have you tried to get in touch with Dave and fix his package on GitHub?

Comment: U'r welcome. Yep, I left a comment on his blog (post about Caliburn.Micro.Autofac [here](http://buksbaum.us/2010/08/20/bootstrapping-caliburn-micro-with-autofac/)) but he didn't answer.

Comment: I think you can just make a change and make a commit request.